# Where to start with Entity Framework

Tags: .net, entity-framework, .net-3.5

Anyone know a good book or post about how to start in EF? I have seen the DnrTV any other place?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Mike Taulty's Blog: http://mtaulty.com/CommunityServer/blogs/mike_taultys_blog/archive/category/1024.aspx

A great EF intro deck: http://mtaulty.com/CommunityServer/blogs/mike_taultys_blog/archive/2008/03/13/10235.aspx

And these ADO.NET Data Services screencasts are nice too: http://mtaulty.com/CommunityServer/blogs/mike_taultys_blog/archive/2008/01/25/10152.aspx

ADO.NET Entity Framework MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399572.aspx

ADO.NET Entity Framework forums: http://forums.microsoft.com/msdn/ShowForum.aspx?ForumID=533&SiteID=1

ADO.NET team blog: http://blogs.msdn.com/adonet/archive/tags/Entity+Framework/default.aspx

Programming LINQ and the ADO.NET Entity Framework Webcast: http://blogs.msdn.com/adonet/archive/2008/01/28/programming-linq-and-the-ado-net-entity-framework-webcast.aspx

Answer (score 1):

[Jason's DotNet Architecture Blog](http://dotnet-architecture-jdo.blogspot.com/2008/08/adonet-entity-framework-part.html) has a tutorial that gets you started with the basics, using the MS SQL Server [AdventureWorks](http://www.codeplex.com/MSFTDBProdSamples) sample database.

Answer (score 0):

[Alex James, Program Manager on the ADO.Net team](http://blogs.msdn.com/alexj/) at microsoft also has the odd good post on EF especially around Metadata.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very decent article on EF http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_general/netframeworkclasses/article.php/c15489/