# ADO.NET Entity Framework tutorials

Tags: entity-framework, ado.net

Does anyone know of any good tutorials on ADO.NET Entity Framework?

There are a few useful links here at [Stack OverFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42826/where-to-start-with-entity-framework), and I've found one tutorial at [Jason's DotNet Architecture Blog](http://dotnet-architecture-jdo.blogspot.com/2008/08/adonet-entity-framework-part.html), but can anyone recommend any other good tutorials? 
Any tutorials available from Microsoft, either online or as part of any conference/course material?

Comment: Related question: [How should I get started learning about ADO.NET Entity Framework?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/258840/how-should-i-get-started-learning-about-adonet-entity-framework)

Comment: Lots of online courses here covering EF and LINQ, first hour is free for all of them: https://learninglineapp.com/schedule

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Microsoft offers [.NET 3.5 Enhancements Training Kit](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=355c80e9-fde0-4812-98b5-8a03f5874e96&displaylang=en) it contains documentation and sample code for ADO.NET EF

Comment: This is great, here's the updated link for .Net 4.0 http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23507

Answer (score 5):

Here are some that Julie Lerman wrote:
http://www.thedatafarm.com/blog/2008/04/04/EightEntityFrameworkTutorialsOnDataDeveloperNET.aspx

And here's of course some info from Microsoft:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386876.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Sample application from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399296.aspx)

And some inside information from [ADO.NET Team Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/adonet/)

Comment: The team blog has some good tutorials, like the Sorting and Paging link.

Answer (score 3):

Try this link you may get some best ideas...

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa697427(VS.80).aspx

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ADO.NET_Entity_Framework

This one is nice try this....

http://davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2007/03/19/ADONETEntityFrameworkObjectServicesTutorial.aspx

http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_general/netframeworkclasses/article.php/c15489/..