# What is the best starting point on the Entity Framework from MS?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

Please give me the direction of the best guidance on the Entity Framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a list of some tutorials available in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62110/adonet-entity-framework-tutorials).

[This](http://forums.microsoft.com/msdn/ShowForum.aspx?ForumID=533&SiteID=1) is a useful Entity Framework forum.

For me, the most useful reference for learning about the Entity Framework when I started using it was [Daniel Simmons' FAQ](http://blogs.msdn.com/dsimmons/pages/entity-framework-faq.aspx).  Check it out!

Answer (score 2):

Mike Taulty has a series of blog entries [here](http://mtaulty.com/CommunityServer/blogs/mike_taultys_blog/archive/category/1024.aspx) that would be worth reading. But first - make sure you really, really want the complexity of EF; NHibernate, LINQ-to-SQL, etc make better answers in many cases. There are a number of issues with the EF approach (not least the forced base class and the much moire complicated xml - barely comprehensible).

I'm not saying don't use it: just make sure you need what it offers (at the price of complexity) first...