# Getting started with Entity Framework in VS.NET 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, entity-framework

What exactly do I need to get started with Entity Framework in VS.net 2008?

I am downloading SP1 for vs.net 2008 as I type this, anything else I am missing?

From what I understand I will have to create some XML and then use a .exe tool to spit out the code?

Answer (score 4):

This question has been asked before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/182497/what-is-the-best-starting-point-on-the-entity-framework-from-ms#182539)...

However, I'll reiterate my answer to that question:
There is a list of some tutorials available in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62110/adonet-entity-framework-tutorials).

[This](http://forums.microsoft.com/msdn/ShowForum.aspx?ForumID=533&SiteID=1) is a useful Entity Framework forum.

For me, the most useful reference for learning about the Entity Framework when I started using it was [Daniel Simmons' FAQ](http://blogs.msdn.com/dsimmons/pages/entity-framework-faq.aspx). Check it out!

Answer (score 0):

VS2008 SP1 comes with Entity Framework and a designer for EF project items (ADO.NET Entity Data Model), but you can use the command line tools as well if you need fine grained control.

So once you install the SP, you're good to go.