# ASP.NET database connection and queries

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm used to PHP style MVC frameworks which are a little different from the way ASP's MVC frameworks work.

Is there a built in database class? Or do I need to code my own database class using a web.conf connection string?

With PHP's MVC frameworks you simply add your database connection information into a database and then query it with something like:

```
$results = $this->db->query("select * from table");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not quite that simple, but you have a lot more flexibility. Check this link out: http://www.dotnetperls.com/sqlconnection -- It has some getting started for doing exactly what you've outlined (though I HIGHLY recommend you use sprocs or at a minimum, paramaterized sql, not direct sql).

With that said, I suggest you look into [Linq-To-SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3657533/86860) or [Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62110/86860). Any on-line sampels you find will probably use one of these technologies, and they do make things very nice and simple.

Comment: -1 for preaching old technologies. If you don't want to use an ORM, then *at least* use ADO.NET - the most recent data access technology. In this case 'DbConnection' instead of 'SqlConnection'.

Answer (score 1):

Use an ORM like Entity Framework 4.1 or nHibernate. They will handle the database connection internally and therefore abstract away some of the complexities of safely opening/closing connections. Then all you need to provide is a connection string.