# How should I get started learning about ADO.NET Entity Framework?

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, entity-framework, ado.net

So here I am just about to start a big project using LINQ to SQL and then I read this:

[Is LINQ to SQL Truly Dead?](http://www.infoq.com/news/2008/11/DLINQ-Future) by Jonathan Allen for InfoQ.com

Well, I don't want to be supporting LINQ to SQL indefinitely if it's a dead end.  So, how should I get started learning about ADO.NET Entity Framework?

Comment: You should make this a community wiki.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

How Do I...? Videos

- [How Do I Get Started with the Entity Framework?](http://blogs.msdn.com/adonet/archive/2008/05/20/how-do-i-new-entity-framework-videos.aspx)
- [How Do I Use the new Entity Data Source?](http://blogs.msdn.com/adonet/archive/2008/05/20/how-do-i-new-entity-framework-videos.aspx)
- [How Do I Serialize a Graph with the Entity Framework?](http://blogs.msdn.com/adonet/archive/2008/05/20/how-do-i-new-entity-framework-videos.aspx)
- [How do I use Entity Client?](http://blogs.msdn.com/adonet/archive/2008/05/20/how-do-i-new-entity-framework-videos.aspx)
- [ADO.NET Entity Designer Video - CTP 2](http://www.asp.net/learn/3.5-SP1/video-245.aspx)

Webcasts

- [MSDN Webcast: Framework Masterclass: LINQ to Entities (Level 200)](http://www.asp.net/learn/webcasts/webcast-181.aspx)

Answer (score 6):

Books

Are there no books published yet that teach the Microsoft ADO.NET Entity Framework?

[Programming the Microsoft® ADO.NET Entity Framework http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/418vMwHm9nL._SL160_AA115_.jpg](http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/418vMwHm9nL._SL160_AA115_.jpg)
Programming the Microsoft® ADO.NET Entity Framework (PRO-Developer)
by David Sceppa
**Dec 10, 2008**

[Programming Entity Framework http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51j8llSWYyL._SL160_AA115_.jpg](http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51j8llSWYyL._SL160_AA115_.jpg)
Programming Entity Framework
by Julia Lerman
**Jan 15, 2009**

[Professional ADO.NET 3.5 with LINQ and the Entity Framework http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/21ALxQeeJWL._SL160_AA115_.jpg](http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/21ALxQeeJWL._SL160_AA115_.jpg)
Professional ADO.NET 3.5 with LINQ and the Entity Framework
by Roger Jennings
**Feb 9, 2009**

[Pro SQL Server 2008 Entity Framework (Pro) http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/41Q1111Df8L._SL160_AA115_.jpg](http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/41Q1111Df8L._SL160_AA115_.jpg)
Pro SQL Server 2008 Entity Framework (Pro)
by Jim Wightman
**Mar 2, 2009**

Answer (score 2):

Search in Google Books and have a preview read of PRO ADO.NET Entity Framework 4.0 book. It looks quite good. Here the a link.

http://books.google.co.in/books?id=mJwXCgFhtPMC&pg=PA1&source=gbs_toc_r&cad=4#v=onepage&q&f=false

Answer (score 1):

Conference Sessions

[PDC 2008 Entity Framework Futures session](http://channel9.msdn.com/pdc2008/TL20/)

Answer (score 1):

Related questions:

- [ADO.NET Entity Framework tutorials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62110/adonet-entity-framework-tutorials)
- [Where to start with Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42826/where-to-start-with-entity-framework)

Comment: Here is another related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/182497/what-is-the-best-starting-point-on-the-entity-framework-from-ms#182539