# Get data type of a SQL Server column using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sqldatatypes

I'm not sure what exactly I'm doing wrong, can someone correct it please? I need to determine the type of a retrieved column from a SQL Server database using C#.

Say, I have this:

```
SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection("Sql Connection String");
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM [TableName]", cn);
SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

while (rdr.Read())
{
    for (int c = 0; c < rdr.VisibleFieldCount; c++)
    {
        System.Type type = rdr.GetFieldType(c);

        //So can I do this? (Pseudo-code)
        //switch(type)
        //{
        //case string:
        //case int:
        //case DateTime:
        //etc.
        //}
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't use a context? Why don't you use LinqToSql or Entity Framework?

Comment: Yes. I don't know what those are. Do you have a link I can check?

Comment: Check out this related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/258840/how-should-i-get-started-learning-about-ado-net-entity-framework

Comment: It seems to me you should **know** what your database table's schema is and thus youshould **know** what those types are.....

Comment: It would be a lot easier to use something like [Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/aa937723) - it will handle a lot of those issues for you, and shield you from the boring details of data access...

Comment: @marc_s Not always the case. We work on projects where the sole purpose of the program is to convert the database from one type to another.  The source schema may change (3rd party) so you have to adapt the code to treat the source database as unknown since you have no control of the schema, unless of course you want the code to break whenever there is a change :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
/* ... code .... */

System.Type type = rdr.GetFieldType(c);

switch (Type.GetTypeCode(type))
{
    case TypeCode.DateTime:
        break;
    case TypeCode.String:
        break;
    default: break;
}

/* ... code .... */
```

Comment: Thanks, dude. It works, except two cases: when I have a UNIQUEIDENTIFIER and BINARY data types. Both are returned as Object, when they should be Guid and Byte[]. Any idea how to handle that?

Comment: @ahmd0: `if (type == typeof(System.Guid))` for instance.

Comment: Correct ... you could do that in the `default` block of the `switch` statement ...

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code that worked for me:

```
SqlCommand ubCommand = new SqlCommand(sqltext);
ubCommand.Connection = ubConnection;
SqlDataReader ubReader = null;
ubReader = ubCommand.ExecuteReader();
ubReader.Read();
schednum = ToInt32(ubReader["ScheduleNum"].ToString());
int fieldNum;
lbl_schedule.Text = $"Schedule {schednum}";
for (i = 0; i < num_fields; i++)
{
 fieldNum = ubReader.GetOrdinal(fields[i]);
 values[i] = ubReader[fieldNum].ToString();
 types[i] = ubReader.GetFieldType(fieldNum);
 // Check types[i].Name for the results, like "String" or "Decimal"
}
ubReader.Close();
ubConnection.Close();
```