# Create .mdb from ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to create .mdb (Microsoft Access Database) from SQL Server table through ASP.NET.
I would manage to create .mdb file and also download.

But main issue is that all fields in .mdb document is in Memo by default. It is not feasible for me
How can i get access columns datatype according to SQL server datatype.

I would try to create and download .mdb with 3 to 4 different type of methods but all methods have same issue.

Comment: Please show the code you currently use to export a .mdb file from SQL Server.

Comment: is [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9712698/get-data-type-of-a-sql-server-column-using-c-sharp) what you are looking for ?

Comment: its generated dynamically. columns are not fix. but main issue is that suppose One field in SQL server table in numeric(5,2) but in .mdb files all fields are in Memo. I want that field in number in .mdb file.